# Why do I have to refresh page manually after delete?

Tags: reactjs

When I delete a circuit (via link on details page) and redirect back to the home page, the object I deleted is still there until I manually refresh the page.

I have tried passing in `props` through the router:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <CircuitList {...props} /> } />
```

I have tried moving the delete function from the detail view container to the list view container, but cannot figure out how to pass the function down through the components.

The delete action

```
    handleDeleteCircuit = (event) => {
        const circuitID = this.props.match.params.id;

        axios.delete(`link-to-api`, this.state);
        this.props.history.push('/');
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
```

Every time I delete a circuit, it deletes from the api, but when it redirects to the home page, it's still there until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: Are you refetching the items on `componentDidMount` in HomePage?

Comment: No, I am deleting them on a detail-view page and redirecting to the homepage.

Comment: You need to show how your fetching and setting the data in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What you see in render is what you have in your state.**

TL;DR
You need to update your state.

---

So you have two ways.

1. Optimistic update, fire delete api to server + setState to delete data in your state. And after you receive response from delete api, act accordingly.
2. After fire delete api, re-fetch the whole data from server again and update state.

I would suggest option 1 because it feels quicker for user.

---

Some extra concept here is.

1. If you want to share state (data) with your "CircuitList" and "CircuitDetail" page. You should store circuits in some parent, like App (or Redux state) and then pass them down to each component.
2. Again, the optimistic update pattern. Fire API + setState immediately... revert back if things go wrong.

Let me know if you feel like any more help :)

---

Below is what you can do.

```
// assuming you have your data in App, state.circuits
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    circuits: [
      { id: 1, title: 'Circuit 1' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Circuit 2' },
      { id: 3, title: 'Circuit 3' },
    ],
  }

  afterDeleteCircuit = (circuitID) => {

    // state, before delete anything
    const currentCircuits = this.state.circuits;

    // Remove deleted item from state.
    this.setState({
      circuits: currentCircuits.filter(circuit => circuit.id !== circuitID),
    });

    // Fire delete API
    axios
      .delete(`link-to-api`, this.state)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 'error') {
          // Oops, something went wrong. Let's get that deleted Id back.
          this.setState({
            circuits: currentCircuits,
          });

          // Show Error message here.
        } else {

          // Delete successfully, do nothing.
          // Because we already remove the deleted id from state.

          // Show success message here.


        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <CircuitList {...props} circuits={this.state.circuits} /> } />
        <Route path='/circuits/:id' render={(props) => <CircuitDetail {...props} onDelete={this.afterDeleteCircuit} /> } />

      </Router>
    );
  }
}


class CircuitList extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { circuits } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {circuits.map(circuit => (
           <li>{circuit.title} <Link to={`/circuit/${circuit.id}`}>Edit</Link></li>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class CircuitDetail extends React.Component {

  handleDelete = (e) => {
    const { match, history } = this.props;
    const id = match.params.id;
    this.props.onDelete(id);

    history.push('/');
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        // Delete button
        <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Would anything change if my data was in CircuitList vs. App?

Comment: Is CircuitDetail in App or CircuitList?

Comment: Anyway, you could use this principle when designing where to keep state/data.... "data always pass down, event always pass up". So it's an anti-pattern to pass data up (CircuitList => App) before passing it down to CircuitDetail. That's why store data at <App /> make sense in react perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I reorganized my app and it deletes but it doesn't redirect to the homepage. Do I need to add `this.history.push('/')?

Comment: For some reason when I add `this.props.history.push('/');` it no longer deletes _and_ it doesn't redirect.

Comment: is 'afterDeleteCircuit' being called? console.log should clarify the problem

Comment: It's successfully deleting the object, but I'm getting a 404 error with `Cannot GET from api` and an `Uncaught (in promise) Error:`.

How can it be deleting but not be called?

Comment: Try replace axios.delete(`link-to-api`) with real path to api.

Comment: I did. I only put link-to-api in the question because it wasn't important to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove elements from the state (if this is in react state then remove from react state. If it is in redux then remove element from the redux state)

Or you can fetch all the items again from backend while your **index** route is mounting again (in **componentDidMount**) but as network calls are heavier than state manipulation. I'd go for optimistic approach of deleting the items from the state (whether it's react or redux or any other state management library you're using)

```
 handleDeleteCircuit = async (event) => {
   const circuitID = this.props.match.params.id;
   await axios.delete(`link-to-api`, this.state);
   const circuits = [...this.state.circuits]; 
   const index = array.indexOf(circuitID)
   //or remove element from the redux state
   if (index !== -1) {
     circuits.splice(index, 1);
     this.setState({circuits});
   }
    this.props.history.push('/');
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand, if I use the first example, this is supposed to manipulate the state on the homepage so the consts and names should be the same?

Comment: Obviously not, but then you need to send some callback to this component. So that you can tell homepage about what circuitID is been deleted

Comment: Is the array in `array.indexOf` supposed to reference the new array circuits in your code?

Also -- this deletes the object but does not redirect only if I remove `this.forceUpdate();` but when I include forceUpdate, it doesn't delete.

Comment: You don't have to do `forceUpdate` if you're changing the route. `array.indexOf` finds the index of `circuitId` you want to delete in the array

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code that removes the circuit from the circuit list.

Something like this :

```js
let this.state.circuits = this.state.circuits.filter((circuit) => {
    return circuit.id == circuitId
})
```

I'm not familiar with React so maybe this requires some changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a redux Store to manage the items in the `CircuitList`, one possible cause is that even though the Entry is deleted via api call, the data still persists in the redux store, which will need to be refreshed aswell once the entry is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived on your problem, and quickly found out what I was missing in my code. So sharing for others.

Be sure to check if you have added dependencies in the useEffect. Because when you delete, the state gets modified but since you haven't added state in dependency array then it will not look it for any changes , hence not updating the UI.

So simply be sure to add state in which you are fetching data in useEffect dependency array.